# Fatal error clean install .net 4.0 on windows server 2008r2

Tags: iis, .net-4.0, windows-server-2008

It starts rolling back when it is installing the Client profile.

Atm there are no installed .net 4.0 versions on the server.

Anybody has some tips on how to fix this?

Event logs:
error 1310: error writing to file c:/windows/system32/msvcr100_clr0400.dll
system error 0 verify that you have access to that directory

Comment: Have you checked the Event Logs?

Comment: Yes: edited original post. 
The file in question is 0kb
edit: typo in event log ^^

Comment: Have you tried to `Run as Administrator` the executable?

Comment: Yes. It failed. Fataly

Answer (score 1):

First, run the following  [.NET Framework setup verification tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Components-PostAttachments/00-08-99-90-04/netfx_5F00_setupverifier_5F00_new.zip).

If the tool finds any issues, just run the [Version 2 of the Microsoft .NET Framework repair tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2698555).

You will find a user's guide about the verification tool [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx).

Comment: You have to have .net installed to check the installation it seems, 'cause it only finds up to version 3.5
We did manage to replace msvcr100_clr0400.dll and now the error changed into: User cancelled installation ( but this is not logged in the event logs)